# Selecting multiple ranges in a Google Sheets formula using a Mac

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having issues using keyboard shortcuts to select a range for any variable after the first variable in a Google Sheets function.
Here is a simple example.

Let's say I'm trying to write a **sumif** function in Google Sheets. I'd like to use keyboard shortcuts to select my ranges, but I can only do so for the first variable in the function.

Let's say I have an x in column A that indicates the column I want to sum, and column B contains the value I want to sum.  In Excel, I can

- type =sumif(
- place my cursor in the first cell for the criteria
- CMD + Shift + Down arrow to select the range for the criteria,
- ,"=x",
- place my cursor in the first cell for the value column
- CMD + Shift + Down arrow to select the range for the value column
- )

So the final formula might look something like `=sumif(A2:A300,"=x",B2:B300)`
However, in Google Sheets the keyboard shortcuts only work for the first variable.

I also tried clicking in the first cell, holding down just the shift key, and using the down arrow key to highlight one cell at a time, and that didn't work either.

I did a few other tests.

- I typed `=sum(B2:B300)` and was able to use the keyboard shortcut, but If I try `=sum(b2:b50,b51:b300)`, I can use the keyboard shortcut for the first range and not the second.
- I tried `sum(b2:b50)+sum(b51:b300)` to see if I could use the shortcut in a second function in the same formula, and I couldn't.
- I ensured the light grey bracket appeared before clicking on the first cell of the second range.
  My conclusion is that the shortcuts only work in the first variable of a function.  I know I can use a mouse, or I can manually type the function, but I have been using these keyboard shortcuts in Excel for likely a decade, and I'm just more efficient this way. "Old dog new tricks" I guess.  I'm hoping someone knows something I can do to make this work in Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Cell selection through the keyboard or mouse works fine for an arbitrary number of formula arguments.

The cell selection mode is context-sensitive. When you are editing a formula, the mode gets activated after you type an argument delimiter (usually comma), or an opening parenthesis `(`, or an operator such as `=`, `<>`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `&`.

You can also activate and deactivate the mode manually by pressing **Control+E** while editing a formula (this is one of the few shortcuts that requires the use of **Control** key on macOS.)

When cell selection does not appear to be working, the reason is often the use of an incorrect argument delimiter. The delimiter is comma `,` in locales that use period as decimal mark, and semicolon `;` in locales that use comma as decimal mark.

To set the delimiter, choose the correct locale in **File > Settings**. The locale setting is per spreadsheet. New spreadsheets inherit their locale from Google Account settings.